# Django Error for property

Tags: python, django

We are running the below **code**:

```
import configparser
def populate_skillgroup(request):
    print("djangoo app")
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('Supervisor.properties')
    user_name = config.get('credentials', 'db_credentials.user_name')
    password = config.get('credentials', 'db_credentials.password')
    db_name = config.get('credentials', 'db_credentials.database_name')
```

However we are getting an **error**:

> Exception Type:   NoSectionError Exception Value:  No section:
>   'credentials'

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: What is confusing you about this? It's telling you you don't have a "credentials" section in your config file.

Comment: Are u sure that you have credentials section in Supervisor.properties file?

Comment: and this has absolutely nothing to do with django whatsoever...

Comment: BTW Django already has it's own settings features with databases configuration, automatic database connections handling etc...

Comment: Yes we do have the credentials in the supervisor properties

Comment: Then you should show that file (anonymised, obviously).